# make applescript close keynote after presentation is over

Tags: applescript, presentation, keynote

does anyone know how i would achieve the following?

i want to make applescript close Keynote AFTER the slideshow is finished. any idea?
mybe via the class "playing" in keynotes application properties?
but i dont know hw to write it.

my code so far

```
tell application "Keynote" to open "/Users/bla/Desktop/bla1.key"
delay 3
set var to properties of application "Keynote"
repeat
if var contains "playing:false" then
exit repeat
end if
delay 1
end repeat

do shell script "killall 'Keynote'"
```

thx :)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the playing property with just `tell app "Keynote" to playing`:

```
tell application "Keynote"
    open "/tmp/temp.key"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Keynote"
    click button "Play" of tool bar 1 of window 1
end tell
tell application "Keynote"
    repeat while playing
        delay 1
        say "a"
    end repeat
end tell
say "b"
```

Comment: omg you are a  genius :) it worked . now i only have to get the loop of both going :) thx

Comment: `repeat 3 times
 tell application "Keynote"
  open "/Users/bla/Desktop/1.key"
 end tell
 tell application "Keynote"
  delay 3
  repeat while playing
   delay 1
  end repeat
 end tell
 tell application "Keynote" to quit
 delay 1
 
 tell application "Keynote"
  open "/Users/bla/Desktop/2.key"
 end tell
 tell application "Keynote"
  delay 3
  repeat while playing
   delay 1
  end repeat
 end tell
 tell application "Keynote" to quit
 delay 1
 
end repeat`